# Get keyword not highlighted (SO)

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

When I was browsing SO, I came upon a unexpected syntax highlighting quirk. In C# code, the "set" keyword, used in properties, was highlighted, but not "get". Could this be changed?

Here's a sample from a SO answer that I screen-captured.

[image: Image illustrating property us]

Comment: In particular, the lines reading "**Stack Exchange does not have its own syntax highlighting engine.** It uses Google Code Prettify. Therefore, any bugs and feature requests regarding syntax highlighting cannot be handled by Stack Exchange and should be directed to the team behind Google Code Prettify.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. That's good to know.